Is exposed rebar in foundation a problem?
Rebar sticks out of the foundation of my house between my garage and driveway (in the gap between the two concrete pours). It is exposed, and in many places the foundation around it is cracking. Is this a big problem? Little problem? Or no problem?


That's probably not your "foundation". That's just the garage slab--the floor. Sometimes a thickened-edge slab serves as a foundation, but it's fairly rare.
The only likely problem is that you've had movement in the slabs--probably in the driveway, either due to gravity or ice pressure. The fact that rebar is exposed is just a visually unappealing symptom of that. As long as the actual house foundation (frost footings and below-grade walls) aren't affected it's just aesthetic. You'd have to show us more than one portrait of the rebar to get more advice.

...although the rebar will now rust and so expand, gradually cracking the concrete it's in. There is supposed to be a "coverage" of at least 25mm of concrete between any rebar inside the concrete and the surface of the concrete, to "keep the rebar inside" and prevent the rusting problem.  So this was work poorly done. However, as this answer says, that's probably not the "foundation" of the building, just reinforcing in the garage floor slab or hopefully just in the driveway.

Is it possible to add a protective zinc coating to the exposed rebar to protect against further galvanic corrosion?

It won't help. Concrete is porous, so the metal just inside, where you can't reach, will also rust. It'll take a decade or more for this thing to rust through. It's not something I'd spend more time thinking about.
